# Linking external DPVS application (using Makefile) with DPDK built using Meson

Tags: gcc, makefile

DPVS recommends making use of *dpdk-stable-18.11.2* for build with Makefile. But the current DPDK LTS version 18.11.11 supports *meson-ninja* build system along with Makefile system.

I've been experimenting with the code to `port to a more recent DPDK version` that only supports meson-ninja instead of the deprecated Makefile system. My issue [DPVS link issue](https://github.com/iqiyi/dpvs/issues/704) is that I am unable to resolve the dependency issues when linking against the DPDK that is built using the meson-ninja. The same works without issues when I try to link against the DPDK 18.11 built using Makefiles. I am running a guest OS with NIC *Virtio/E1000* using KVM-QEMU. Guest OS is *Ubuntu 18.04 LTS (x64)*.

DPDK libraries are linked by DPVS project by [dpdk.mk](https://github.com/iqiyi/dpvs/blob/master/src/dpdk.mk), and current linking options are:

```
LIBS += -Wl,--no-as-needed -fvisibility=default \
        -Wl,--whole-archive -lrte_pmd_vmxnet3_uio -lrte_pmd_i40e -lrte_pmd_ixgbe \
        -lrte_pmd_e1000 -lrte_pmd_bnxt -lrte_pmd_ring -lrte_pmd_bond -lrte_ethdev -lrte_ip_frag \
        -Wl,--whole-archive -lrte_hash -lrte_kvargs -Wl,-lrte_mbuf -lrte_eal \
        -Wl,-lrte_mempool -lrte_ring -lrte_cmdline -lrte_cfgfile -lrte_kni \
        -lrte_mempool_ring -lrte_timer -lrte_net -Wl,-lrte_pmd_virtio \
        -lrte_pci -lrte_bus_pci -lrte_bus_vdev -lrte_lpm -lrte_pdump \
        -Wl,--no-whole-archive -lrt -lm -ldl -lcrypto
```

What I've tried so far:

- Verified that linking is successful using Makefile system
- Ensured that there are no 'could not find library' issues by adding the appropriate library path when linking against the Meson build
- I don't want to move it into the apps folder of DPDK and create Meson build files for it yet (haven't learnt it yet).

So, Please help in resolving this linking issue (it seems to be a general issue related to linking with the `-Wl` flag options).

Thanks! :)

---

Edit: Updated error logs

```
cc -D DPVS_MAX_SOCKET=1 -D DPVS_MAX_LCORE=3 -D CONFIG_DPVS_TRACING \
-D CONFIG_DPVS_NEIGH_DEBUG -D CONFIG_DPVS_IPVS_DEBUG -D DPVS_CFG_PARSER_DEBUG \
-D CONFIG_DPVS_IP_HEADER_DEBUG -D CONFIG_DPVS_PDUMP \
-D CONFIG_DPVS_IPSET_DEBUG -D CONFIG_MSG_DEBUG \
-include /home/anshul/loadbalancer/dpdk-stable-18.11.10/sdk/build/include/rte_config.h -march=native \
-DRTE_MACHINE_CPUFLAG_SSE -DRTE_MACHINE_CPUFLAG_SSE2 \
-DRTE_MACHINE_CPUFLAG_SSE3 -DRTE_MACHINE_CPUFLAG_SSSE3 \
-DRTE_MACHINE_CPUFLAG_SSE4_1 -DRTE_MACHINE_CPUFLAG_SSE4_2  \
-D __DPVS__ -DDPVS_VERSION=\"1.8-4\" \
-DDPVS_BUILD_DATE=\"2021.01.25.10:11:27\" \
-Werror -Wstrict-prototypes -Wmissing-prototypes \
-mcmodel=medium -fgnu89-inline -Wno-format-truncation \
-Wno-stringop-truncation -Wstringop-overflow=0 -g -O0 \
-D DEBUG -rdynamic \
-I /home/anshul/loadbalancer/dpdk-stable-18.11.10/sdk/build/include \
-I /home/anshul/loadbalancer/dpvs/src//../include \
-L /home/anshul/loadbalancer/dpdk-stable-18.11.10/sdk/build/lib \
-L /home/anshul/loadbalancer/dpdk-stable-18.11.10/sdk/build/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/ \
-L /home/anshul/loadbalancer/dpdk-stable-18.11.10/sdk/build/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/dpdk/pmds-18.11 \
-Wl,--no-as-needed -fvisibility=default \
-Wl,--whole-archive -lrte_pmd_vmxnet3 -lrte_pmd_i40e -lrte_pmd_ixgbe -lrte_pmd_e1000 -lrte_pmd_bnxt -lrte_pmd_ring -lrte_pmd_bond -lrte_ethdev -lrte_ip_frag \
-Wl,--whole-archive -lrte_hash -lrte_kvargs \
-Wl,-lrte_mbuf -lrte_eal \
-Wl,-lrte_mempool -lrte_ring -lrte_cmdline -lrte_cfgfile -lrte_kni -lrte_mempool_ring -lrte_timer -lrte_net \
-Wl,-lrte_pmd_virtio -lrte_pci -lrte_bus_pci -lrte_bus_vdev -lrte_lpm -lrte_pdump \
-Wl,--no-whole-archive -lrt -lm -ldl -lcrypto \
-Wl,-rpath,/home/anshul/loadbalancer/dpdk-stable-18.11.10/sdk/build/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/ -lpthread -lnuma /home/anshul/loadbalancer/dpvs/src/cfgfile.o ... -o dpvs
/home/anshul/loadbalancer/dpvs/src/netif.o: In function `get_bond_status':
/home/anshul/loadbalancer/dpvs/src/netif.c:4738: undefined reference to `rte_eth_bond_link_monitoring_get'
/home/anshul/loadbalancer/dpvs/src/netif.c:4739: undefined reference to `rte_eth_bond_link_down_prop_delay_get'
/home/anshul/loadbalancer/dpvs/src/netif.c:4740: undefined reference to `rte_eth_bond_link_up_prop_delay_get'
/home/anshul/loadbalancer/dpvs/src/netif.o: In function `set_bond':
/home/anshul/loadbalancer/dpvs/src/netif.c:5030: undefined reference to `rte_eth_bond_link_down_prop_delay_set'
/home/anshul/loadbalancer/dpvs/src/netif.c:5039: undefined reference to `rte_eth_bond_link_up_prop_delay_set'
collect2: error: ld returned 1 exit status
Makefile:71: recipe for target 'dpvs' failed
make[1]: *** [dpvs] Error 1
make[1]: Leaving directory '/home/anshul/loadbalancer/dpvs/src'
Makefile:33: recipe for target 'all' failed
make: *** [all] Error 1
```

---

Update: The currently used options in the `dpdk.mk` are:

```
CFLAGS += -march=native \
          -DRTE_MACHINE_CPUFLAG_SSE \
          -DRTE_MACHINE_CPUFLAG_SSE2 \
          -DRTE_MACHINE_CPUFLAG_SSE3 \
          -DRTE_MACHINE_CPUFLAG_SSSE3 \
          -DRTE_MACHINE_CPUFLAG_SSE4_1 \
          -DRTE_MACHINE_CPUFLAG_SSE4_2 

LIBS += -L $(DPDKDIR)/lib
LIBS += -L $(DPDKDIR)/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/
LIBS += -L $(DPDKDIR)/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/dpdk/pmds-20.11
 
LIBS += -Wl,--no-as-needed -fvisibility=default \
        -Wl,--whole-archive -lrte_net_vmxnet3 -lrte_net_i40e -lrte_net_ixgbe \
        -lrte_net_e1000 -lrte_net_bnxt -lrte_net_ring -lrte_ip_frag \
        -Wl,--whole-archive -lrte_hash -lrte_kvargs -Wl,-lrte_mbuf -lrte_eal \
        -Wl,--whole-archive -l:librte_net_bond.a -l:librte_ethdev.a \
        -Wl,-lrte_mempool -lrte_ring -lrte_cmdline -lrte_cfgfile -lrte_kni \
        -lrte_mempool_ring -lrte_timer -lrte_net -Wl,-lrte_net_virtio \
        -lrte_pci -lrte_bus_pci -lrte_bus_vdev -lrte_lpm -lrte_pdump \
        -Wl,--no-whole-archive -lrt -lm -ldl -lcrypto -lrte_telemetry

LIBS += -Wl,-rpath,$(DPDKDIR)/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/
```

Summary:

- Removed `-DRTE_COMPILE_TIME_CPUFLAGS=RTE_CPUFLAG_SSE,RTE_CPUFLAG_SSE2,RTE_CPUFLAG_SSE3,RTE_CPUFLAG_SSSE3,RTE_CPUFLAG_SSE4_1,RTE_CPUFLAG_SSE4_2` from `CFLAGS` to avoid redefinition errors.
- Updated library paths in `LIBS` variable to reflect paths to the SDK. The SDK folder (`DPDKDIR`) is the folder where `ninja install` had installed the files and libraries to.
- Added `-Wl,-rpath,$(DPDKDIR)/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/` option for stray issues referencing some libraries `*.so.11`
- Linking to static libraries for bonding and ethdev using `-l:librte_net_bond.a -l:librte_ethdev.a` options.

---

Comment: Please update the ticket OS, DPDK/DPDK LTS version, The NIC you are using, and the error log for which you are getting the error. Since the error is not related to DPDK build or DPDK meson, I am editing it as `Makefile` and flagging the question for edit for more clarity.

Comment: @VipinVarghese Many thanks for the edit suggestion. 

The OS is Ubuntu 18.04 LTS (x64 system). Currently, I'm using the Virtio/E1000 interface NIC drivers for use inside KVM. The error logs have been updated in the question.

Comment: Also, have made some progress regarding fixing some path issues. The original problem still stands - unresolved symbols. :)

Comment: @Anushul in my humble opinion the way in which you are updating `dpdk.mk` for meson build DPDK is incorrect. Especially path which are hardcoded.

Comment: @VipinVarghese Some updates. By using static linking options for `librte_net_bond` (`-l:librte_net_bond.a`), I am able to link the binary successfully.

Also tried the same using the recent 20.11 DPDK build (changed the pmd to rte names for libraries, and had to add `rte_telemetry` additionally to resolve further dependencies in static linking `librte_ethdev` for `rte_flow` related APIs.

Comment: @VipinVarghese Could you help? What would you require from my end to be able to better guide me?

Comment: I have edited the ticket to reflect the right format, please accept and add the changes you have made to existing dpdk.mk to help you

Comment: since there were no updates from  your end for the changes made in Makefile for reference I had to fork DPVS and make a push request to original repository. Please check if these helps your cause, if yes `accept and upvote`. Also please do not forget to review the push request as it will helps the github community too.

Comment: @VipinVarghese Oh, I had made the updates in the answer. Apologies that I did not leave a followup comment. Will do the needful! :)

Comment: I think what you are stating is you have updates in github and not stack overflow. thanks for confirming

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The issue you are facing is to due improper use of library linking. The easiest solution is to

1. Download DPDK 18.11.11 LTS that supports meson.
2. Build dpdk libraries and install to the desired path.
3. modify dpvs `src/dpdk.mk` to check for libdpdk via pkg-conf
4. modify `src/makefile` to accommodate the changes for DPDK libraries

An explanation for the steps are briefly mentioned in [section 3.24 Buidlign application with installed DPDK](http://doc.dpdk.org/guides/linux_gsg/build_dpdk.html)

[EDIT-1]
note: Since there are no updates on the changes done to Makefile from @Anshul, I have created a [push request](https://github.com/iqiyi/dpvs/pull/708) to support the same.

diff for src/Makefile

```
index 02f288c..f2aefdb 100644
--- a/src/Makefile
+++ b/src/Makefile
@@ -34,10 +34,14 @@ DATE_STRING := $(shell date +%Y.%m.%d.%H:%M:%S)
 # same path of THIS Makefile
 SRCDIR := $(dir $(realpath $(firstword $(MAKEFILE_LIST))))

+ifeq ($(shell pkg-config --exists libdpdk && echo 0),0)
+else
 ifeq ($(RTE_SDK),)
        $(error "The variable RTE_SDK is not defined.")
 endif
 include $(RTE_SDK)/mk/rte.vars.mk
+LIBS += -lpthread -lnuma
+endif

 include $(SRCDIR)/config.mk
 include $(SRCDIR)/dpdk.mk
@@ -62,7 +66,6 @@ else
        CFLAGS += -rdynamic
 endif

-LIBS += -lpthread -lnuma
```

diff for src/dpdk.mk

```
 # MERCHANTABILITY or FITNESS FOR A PARTICULAR PURPOSE.  See the
 # GNU General Public License for more details.
 #
+ifeq ($(shell pkg-config --exists libdpdk && echo 0),0)
+
+CFLAGS += -DALLOW_EXPERIMENTAL_API -static $(shell pkg-config --cflags libdpdk)
+LIBS += $(shell pkg-config --libs --static libdpdk)
+
+else

 ifeq ($(RTE_SDK),)
 $(error "The variable RTE_SDK is not defined.")
@@ -58,3 +64,4 @@ LIBS += -Wl,--whole-archive -lrte_pmd_mlx5 -Wl,--no-whole-archive
 LIBS += -libverbs -lmlx5 -lmnl
 endif

+endif
```